# OpenCV - Unknown array type in function cvarrToMat

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv, uiimage

I'm using `OpenCV`inside one of my projects (iOS app). I'm trying to use `cvMatchTemplate` (Link : [Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html) ) . For some reason I'm getting this error :

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat, file /Volumes/build-storage/build/master_iOS-mac/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 943
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Volumes/build-storage/build/master_iOS-mac/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:943: error: (-5) Unknown array type in function cvarrToMat
```

Running this code:

```
cv::Mat mOriginal, mTemp,res;
UIImageToMat(original, mOriginal);
UIImageToMat(temp, mTemp);

// Crashing at this line
cvMatchTemplate(&mOriginal, &mTemp, &res, CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. **Thank you.**

Comment: Don't use obsolete C api. Use `cv::matchTemplate`

Comment: Hey @Miki . Can't believe i've missed that. Lack of experience i guess. Thanks. Can you post an answer?

Comment: Gave you full credit. :) @Miki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Miki too humble to post his answer :)

```
Don't use obsolete C api. Use cv::matchTemplate
```

Working code:

```
cvMatchTemplate(mOriginal, mTemp, res, CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
```